# Changing scale to lat/long using sf objects in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I'm afraid I just cannot figure this out. I am trying to plot regions in states/US territories using collections of counties; [here is an example file (AK_Test.csv)](https://github.com/Doc-Midnight/Test_Dir).

The data is taken from the `urbn_map` data set `territories_counties`. It's my understanding that this data uses the "simple features" (`sf`) geometry, so all of the polygon data is stored in the `geometry` column for each county-level object.

Here is the code I am using to plot:

```
g <- ggplot(ak_test)
g <- g + geom_sf(aes(geometry = geometry, fill = Region), 
                 color = "black", show.legend = FALSE)
g <- g + geom_sf_label_repel(aes(geometry = geometry, label = County))
g <- g + coord_sf()
g
```

Here is the output: [image: wrong units]

I do not understand the units on the axes, but I would like them to be in lat/long -- I thought that was the purpose of the `coord_sf()` function. I've tried adding x and y limits (using the approximate boundaries of the state), but when I do that, the image falls off the page.

In other cases, the output appears rotated/tilted (see image with Oregon/Idaho/Montana) - I'm hoping that the conversion to lat/long addresses this as well.[image: rotated states]

Comment: please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: I put the results of the `dput()` command into a file called `AK_Test2` in the same GitHub repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These numbers *are* latitude / longitude, but they are in a different co-ordinate system from the one you want. You need to re-project the data using an appropriate crs:

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Doc-Midnight/Test_Dir/main/AK_Test2"

ak_test <- source(url)

ak_test <- ak_test$value

ak_test$geometry <- st_transform(ak_test$geometry, "WGS84")

g <- ggplot(ak_test)
g <- g + geom_sf(aes(geometry = geometry, fill = Region), 
                 color = "black", show.legend = FALSE)
g <- g + geom_sf_label(aes(geometry = geometry, label = County))
g + labs(x = "longitude", y = "latitude")
```

[image]

Note, I have no idea where `geom_sf_label_repel` comes from, so I have used non-repeling labels since they are incidental to the question.

Comment: Super clear - thanks. The `geom_sf_label_repel` comes from the `ggsflabel` package. It works like `ggrepel`, but for `sf` objects (is my understanding).

Comment: The latitude doesn't seem right, does it? I think Alaska is between 52 and 72 degrees North...

Comment: You're right, and the longitude appears wrong too. The above transformation should work, so I'm a bit puzzled. Can I ask where the data came from?

Comment: The numerical data (i.e., what we're talking about) is straight from the `urbn` project. I got it using: `get_urbn_map(map = "territories_counties", sf = TRUE)`